# Hide menu bar along with fragment

Tags: android, layout, menu, fragment

How to hide menu bar along before loading new fragment ?

Explain : Currently I'm creating android application use sliding menu, action bar and fragment.
I have `MainActivity` contains :
 - `HomeFragment` : in this, menu bar is shown.
 - `LoadingBattleFragment` : in this menu bar is hiden.

When click a button in `HomeFragment` , change whole screen to `LoadingBattleFragment` and because of hiding menu bar so . It doesn't like inflating whole layout to new layout. Actually It likes : display home_layout + menubar => display loadingbattle_layout + menubar => hide menubar. Is there any way to : display home_layout + menubar => display loadingbattle_layout + without menubar.